# How can a 32-bit program read the "real" 64-bit version of the registry?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, registry

I'm trying to read *HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run* with `OpenKeyReadOnly`, and `GetValueNames`, but it's returning values from *HKLM\SOFTWARE\**Wow6432Node**\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run* instead.

How can I read the 64-bit values instead of from a redirect to the 32-bit key?

The program was run as an administrative account. I also tried `RegOpenKeyEx` and `RegEnumValue`.

I'm using Delphi 2010.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

you must use the [`KEY_WOW64_64KEY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724878%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) value when open the Registry with the [`TRegistry`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Registry.TRegistry) class.

from MSDN :

> **KEY_WOW64_64KEY**  Indicates that an
>   application on 64-bit Windows should
>   operate on the 64-bit registry view.
>   This flag is ignored by 32-bit
>   Windows.
>
> This flag must be combined using the
>   OR operator with the other flags in
>   this table that either query or access
>   registry values.

try this sample app.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows,
  Classes,
  registry,
  SysUtils;


procedure ReadRegistry;
var
  Registry: TRegistry;
  List    : TStrings;
begin
  Registry := TRegistry.Create(KEY_WRITE OR KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
  //Registry := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ OR KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
  List     := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Registry.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    if Registry.OpenKeyReadOnly('\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run') then
    begin
       Registry.GetValueNames(List);
       Writeln(List.Text);
    end;
    Registry.CloseKey;
  finally
    Registry.Free;
    List.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
  try
   ReadRegistry();
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: AFAIK this example is wrong because OpenKeyReadOnly will reset the Access property to KEY_READ without the KEY_WOW64_64KEY. So you are still reading the 32-bits version. Maybe later Delphi version preserve the KEY_WOW64_64KEY, but I cannot check that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for question editing, with English at me are bad while... 
Has found still: Reg.Access:=KEY_WOW64_64KEY or KEY_ALL_ACCESS;

Comment: @TheFox, I tested the code in delphi 2007 and delphi XE under Windows 7 64 bits, and works ok in both versions.

Comment: This works, but there is a catch if you want to enumerate the registry recursively.  If you pass KEY_WOW64_64KEY and hit one of the Wow6432Node keys (which in regedit is the 32-bit registry) it will instead return the 64-bit base key again, so you can descend indefinitely.  The only workaround we've found is to loop up through the key names and revert to 32-bit access if any of the parents is named 'Wow6432Node'.

Comment: OMG!  I found this while posting a question, desperate for help.  I had concluded, after a day of debugging, that the same app (Delphi XE5) would WORK as 64-bit, and FAIL as 32-bit.  I was going nuts.  Very glad to see this here.

Comment: Dang!  WOW64 stuff is not available in Delphi2005.  Yes, yes, we are upgrading from that.  Any workarounds besides hacking our Registry unit?

Comment: FYI, the DXE5 version just needs a few modifications to compile in D2005.  Seems to work fine.