# Delphi: Detect a pending reboot (such as from Windows Update)

Tags: delphi, detection, reboot

**Using Delphi, is there a way to check for a pending reboot (such as from Windows Update)?**

In my research, I saw a way to do this using C++ ([here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150921-00/?p=91551)) , but it uses a library that I could not locate or find an equivalent in Delphi.

Comment: Possible solution in VB: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21790086/3164070

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution from Raymond Chen, to which you linked, can easily be translated to Delphi, although the mechanisms in Delphi have slightly different names and syntax.

The [documentation for *ISystemInformation*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/aa386095(v%3Dvs.85)) says:

> You can create an instance of this interface by using the *SystemInformation* coclass. Use the *Microsoft.Update.SystemInfo* program identifier to create the object.

An example:

```
program CheckRebootRequired;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, Winapi.ActiveX, System.Win.ComObj, System.Variants;

procedure Main;
var
  SysInfo: OleVariant;
  RebootRequired: OleVariant;
begin
  SysInfo := CreateOleObject('Microsoft.Update.SystemInfo');
  if not VarIsNull(SysInfo) then
  begin
    RebootRequired := SysInfo.RebootRequired;
    Writeln('Reboot required = ', RebootRequired);
  end
  else
    Writeln('Could not get Update SystemInfo');
end;

begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    try
      Main;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
    end;
  finally
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: I was able to verify that this works fine as my computer needed a restart. Thanks!

Comment: @Andre72127: Thanks for the confirmation. I had no way to test this. <g>

Answer (score 2):

You can check for the existence of the following two registry keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\RebootPending
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired
```

or the registry value

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager
```

If any of these keys / values exist a reboot is pending. Please take note that on 64 bit Windows installations you should query the 64 bit registry. See [How can a 32-bit program read the “real” 64-bit version of the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493303/how-can-a-32-bit-program-read-the-real-64-bit-version-of-the-registry) for information on how to do this from a 32 bit program. Furthermore, I believe the first key `...\Component Based Servicing\RebootPending` only exists in Vista / Server 2008 and later.